Upgrade Typescript for React application
I would like to upgrade Typescript@5.5 for my React application (it is already using Typescript).
After I run yarn add typescript@latest or yarn upgrade typescript@latest, there are changes in package.json and lock file to the latest version without any error.
I don't install typescript globally.
However, the Typescript new features are not usable yet.
E.g I cannot use intersection method for Set.
Could someone help me point out what steps I miss in order to upgrade Typescript?
This is my tsconfig.json.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true, // allow sourcemap support
    "strictNullChecks": true, // enable strict null checks as a best practice
    "module": "commonjs", // specify module code generation
    "jsx": "react", // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
    "target": "ESNext", // specify ECMAScript target version
    "allowJs": false, // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
    "checkJs": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018", "DOM", "ESNext.Array"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "types"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["public/*"],
      "@test/*": ["test/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./build",
    "./distributions"
  ]
}


What errors do you see? Is it your IDE or the application that doesn't see the update

What package manager do you use?

Did you try upgrade? Like this yarn upgrade typescript

Here are some clues - maybe you have TS installed globally? Or maybe other specific configuration.

Hi @MichałTurczyn, thanks for your input. I don't install Typescript globally.
I tried but add and upgrade. They made similar changes. But none of them work for me.

Please [edit] your question to include your tsconfig.json configuration

You need "target": "ES2024" (not sure if this one even works yet) or "target": "ESNext" in your compiler options

I changed "target": "ESNext" (ES2024 is not available). I still cannot use the new features of Typescript.

es2018 in lib seems unnecessary and also possibly a problem. You also haven't answered the question from @Randy above. FYI it works just fine here with "target": "ESNext"

The es2018 in lib causes a problem. Try to replace it with ESNext. Or maybe just remove the lib options

@qrsngky and @Phil, your suggestions works. Change both "target" and "lib" that use another esVersion to ESNext.
It is my IDE that doesn't see the update, when using new feature, I get the linting error Property 'intersection' does not exist on type 'Set<unknown>'.ts(2339).

What version of Node.js are you running? Set.prototype.intersection is not a TypeScript feature, it's a JavaScript one and it's available on Node.js from version 22.0.0 and up.

Are you using ESLint ?
